# Can I hide phone numbers from specific user groups in Office 365?

Tags: office365

Is is possible to hide phone numbers for a specific user group so that they can't see the number in any way possible?
It needs to be hidden in o365, sharepoint, azureAD, exchange online, outlook clients and every other app part of o365 that syncs the number.

The picture is showing a contact card in Outlook. Since I'm the admin I can see every info, but I need to hide the phone numbers from a specific group.
These numbers are shown in many o365 apps and need to be hidden from the group in every app.

[Contact in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm2Qt.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and where the phone is displayed.

Comment: Why have you opened two accounts?

Comment: You can modify the visibility of this property of the user within Microsoft 365 SharePoint Admin Center, specifically, `More Features -> User Profiles -> Manage User Properties` and set the Default Privacy Settings to "Only Me"